# Matlab How to iterate a function through a list

Tags: matlab, list, function, loops, iteration

I need some help iterating over a function that depends on two variables.

So let's say I have a function that depends on two variables. 
Let's call it f = x + y

Now, I have a two lists, one of x variables and one of y variables. For example,
xlist = [1 2 3] and
ylist = [4 5 6]

And I want to go through each element of the lists and plug it into f. For example, set x=1 and then evaluate f for y=4, then y=5, then y=6... and repeat for x=2 and x=3.

Finally, I want to return a matrix of the calculated values. For the example above, the answer should be
[5 6 7];[6 7 8];[7 8 9]

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the function **can't be vectorized** and thus you really need to iterate, a simple way is via [`ndgrid`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) (to create *x*, *y* values that describe all possible pairs) and [`arrayfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) (to iterate over the two *x*, *y* values at the same time):

```
f = @(x,y) x+y; % Or f = @fun, if fun is a function defined elsewhere
xlist = [1 2 3];
ylist = [4 5 6];
[xx, yy] = ndgrid(xlist, ylist); % all pairs
result = arrayfun(f, xx, yy);
```

---

In many cases the function **can be [vectorized](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html)**, which results in faster code. For the example function this would be done defining `f` as

```
f = @(x,y) bsxfun(@plus, x(:), y(:).');
```

or in recent Matlab versions you can exploit [implicit singleton expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) and just write

```
f = @(x,y) x(:)+y(:).';
```

In either case, note that the two arguments of addition are forced to be a column vector (`x(:)`) and a row vector (`y(:).'`), so that singleton expansion will automatically create all pairs:

```
xlist = [1 2 3];
ylist = [4 5 6];
result = f(xlist, ylist);
```

Comment: thank you very much! Just curious, could you give me an example of how to solve a problem if the function can be vectorized?

Comment: @Marcus That's second part of the answer, isn't it? Or what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it would be to use two for loops:

```
x_values=[2,4,6,8];
y_values=[1,3,5,7];
%initialize a matrix with zeros
output_matrix=zeros(length(x_values),length(y_values));
for i=1:length(x_values)
    for j=1:length(y_values)
        output_matrix(i,j)=x_values(i)+y_values(j);
    end 
end

output_matrix
```